# Identify File Type When File Extensions Are Hidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, path, fs

What is the proper way to identify the type of any given file?

So long as one has enabled the option of displaying file extensions, I know there are a couple ways to do it, which are virtually identical to one another.

```
path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.')+1)

const path = require('path')
path.extname(string)
```

But what if somebody has disabled the option of displaying file extensions. In this context, ideally in a cross-platform manner, how can I identify the file type of any given file?

Comment: Do you want something like the unix command `file`?

Comment: @Macabeus i just want to be able to identify the type of file for any given file, ideally in a cross-platform manner

Comment: I thought disabling the file extensions *only* applies to Windows File Explorer and *only* for seeing the files there. Obviously the files still have their extensions, so I always thought that any programmatic read of directory *will* show the full name of the file. But I've never really tried that.

Comment: @VLAZ im just assuming you can disable showing file extensions in other OSs because you can do it in Windows lol. im not too sure if you can still retrieve the filenames when extensions are hidden. i will test that right now

Comment: @VLAZ the file type of a file must at the very least still be retrievable since you can basically have two files of different types named the same thing, so... but say there are two files on your desktop (i.e. `test.txt` and `test.js`), how do you programmatically try to read one file instead of the other or how do you distinguish one file from another if file extensions aren't displayed???

Comment: When you say "type", I assume you mean "the portion of the file's name after the last dot" -- That will be present, regardless of the user's Windows Explorer settings.

Comment: @oldboy you should be addressing them via the full name. I'm not aware of any programmatic read method where you can say something like `open('file')` and it would automatically assume you mean (for example) `file.txt`. Any FS access method I've seen just reports "invalid file" or something to that effect if you have an incomplete name.

Comment: @VLAZ but what if they were only displayed '`test`' and '`test`' and youre searching to see whats in the directory as opposed to trying to read one file specially that u already know the name of. anyways, ok i just tested and yes even if u hide extensions theyre still viewable if u search programmatically

Comment: @aksommerville post that as ur answer and ill accept

Comment: Well, if you programatically list the contents, you'd have the full name of the file. So, the user wouldn't be seeing `file` and `file` to begin with. And even if *you* hide the extension, you'd still know what that extension is. That's how File Explorer works - it just displays a simplified name but can still identify the differnet files. After all, if you open `file` which is actually `file.txt` you won't get the contents of `file.js`. Moreover, File Explorer will show different meta information - creation date, type, etc.

Comment: @VLAZ the user would be seeing `file` and `file`, so long as theyve disabled file extensions tho... anyways, this is all hypothetical, and i just tested and it displays the file types underneath the hood even if theyre disabled on teh surface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "type", I assume you mean "the portion of the file's name after the last dot" -- That will be present, regardless of the user's Windows Explorer settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better approaches, but I can only think of this solution.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

let output = execSync('file ~/textFile')
  .toString()

console.log(output) // will print '/Users/macabeus/textFile: ASCII text'
```

This will only work in Unix systems, so you'll need to use WSL in Windows.

Comment: Just a note - this only works on Linux/Unix based OSes. I think all would have `file` but not sure - perhaps OSX or some Linux distro doesn't.

Comment: thanks. but what if the user doesnt have WSL installed/enabled ??

Comment: @Macabeus wasn't `type` in Windows equivalent to `cat` in *NIX?

Comment: Yeah. I was confused. Well... I can't find an equivalent for Windows...

Comment: @Macabeus I assume there is some PowerShell cmdlet that does something similar, but my PS skills are very low. I think checking the extension is safe enough method to identify files in most cases - `file` is *good* but a lot of times it's an overkill.